# IOS Map Kit Annotation callout to tableview

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, mapkit, callout

Working on a maps app and when I click the annotation callout, i'd like it to move to a detail view controller and have the back button in the upper left to return to the map.  If possible, it should act just like a navigation controller with a table view, but the callout button takes place of clicking the table view cell and the view with the map is the root of the navigation controller.  I've seen it done, but have not been able to find anything that makes sense at all.  The only thing I can get working is a modal view controller and not a "push" segue.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement the callout accessory delegate method, and from there, push your new view controller.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control{
    YourViewController *viewController=[YourViewController initializer];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
}
```